# Repair a hg repo with broken origin?

Tags: mercurial, repair

Not sure how I did it, but I broke my mercurial repo at rev 0...

```
checking files
 WeberVent/Inc/stm32f0xx_it.h@0: 76907c5d3471 not in manifests
 WeberVent/Inc/stm32f0xx_it.h@0: unpacking 76907c5d3471: revlog decompress error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect data check
 WeberVent/Inc/stm32f0xx_it.h@1: unpacking 579dc194b480: revlog decompress error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect data check
 WeberVent/Inc/stm32f0xx_it.h@22: unpacking f20e1ef46f49: revlog decompress error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect data check
 WeberVent/Inc/stm32f0xx_it.h@32: unpacking 8d7ba8ea3a0a: revlog decompress error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect data check
 WeberVent/Inc/stm32f0xx_it.h@34: unpacking b7db2e1be9f1: revlog decompress error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect data check
 WeberVent/Inc/stm32f0xx_it.h@42: unpacking 8a85c32f2277: revlog decompress error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect data check
 WeberVent/Inc/stm32f0xx_it.h@44: unpacking 1330863ae1d5: revlog decompress error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect data check
 WeberVent/Inc/stm32f0xx_it.h@72: unpacking 7ae8c2f9a8e4: revlog decompress error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect data check
 WeberVent/Inc/stm32f0xx_it.h@0: 76907c5d3471 in manifests not found
```

I have a the files at those revisions (yay backups, but only the stm32f0xx_it.h files), but going through 4.3 at https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/RepositoryCorruption just doesn't work:

```
C:\crap\HgFixes>hg clone -r 0 WeberVent2 fix
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
transaction abort!
rollback completed
abort: unexpected error: data/WeberVent/Inc/stm32f0xx_it.h.i@76907c5d3471: no node
```

So now what?  Is there a way to stuff my archived stm32f0xx_it.h files back into the repo and make it whole again, or am I forced to "start a new rev0"?

Comment: Do you have any other clones of this repo? Could you use one of them to substitute for the broken one instead of trying to actually repair it?

Comment: No... all of the repos I have are of same.  I don't have anything with a good rev0...